# jQuery CSS: Dropdown Interaction

Tags: jquery, css

I am having the following issue with my code -> it does not seem to be interacting with the jQuery but I am getting no errors in the js console:

The main dropdown title in this menu is **Trails**

When Trails is hovered over it should show the below `<li>`

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".current a").mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).siblings("ul").show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
       $(this).siblings("ul").hide();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
//Controls the sub li    
#wrapper #contentarea #blue_box .centerblue_txt ul li ul li{
        width:185px;
        padding:5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-top:1px dotted #424242;
        border-bottom:0px;
    }
//Controls the sub ul
    #wrapper #contentarea #blue_box .centerblue_txt ul li ul{
        border:1px solid red;
        display:none;
    }
```

**HTML:** - *This HTML formatting is given by PYROCMS and I have no control over it*

```
<li class="current">
        <a href="">Trials</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="first">
                <a href="">Link One</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link Two</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link Three</a>
            </li>
            <li class="last">
                <a href="">Link Four</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being loaded?

Comment: What does `interacting with the jQuery` mean? Your code certainly does something. http://jsfiddle.net/3JNGC/. Check that your jQuery reference's are correect and that there isn't a conflict with another jQuery library. Are you sure `$` isn't used by something else in the CMS?

Comment: @mrtsherman how could I implement no.conflict into my code?

Comment: use the word `jQuery` instead of `$` or create a global variable and define your own term for the `$` or `jQuery`, like declare `jess = jQuery` then whenever you type `jess` JS will see `jQuery`

Comment: @JTSmith Could you post that as an answer.  Could you also tell me why I cannot navigate to my sub dropdown menu? without it closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer you were asking for Jess.  To help reduce the likelihood of a conflict, you can create your own namespacing.  jQuery itself can be used, most commonly, with the `$` or you can also use the actual word/name `jQuery` in place of the $.  But you can also create your own version with whatever word/name you want.  At the beginning of your script name a variable, in my example I used your name, like so:

```
var jess = jQuery;
```

Then whenever you use `jess` it will use the variables value, which is jQuery. So:

```
jess(document).ready()
```

is equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready()
```

and to:

```
jQuery(document).ready()
```

As far as not being able to see or click the sub menu it's because your jquery call only displays the submenu when you are hovered over the parent element meaning as soon as your mouse moves off it, you lose the submenu.  When it comes to menu's and submenu's, take tea_totaler's advice and use CSS, it's much easier and cleaner to user

Here is a [decent article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/) on namespacing.

If you insist on using jQuery for the submenu, you can use the `.toggle` function rather than the `.show` and `.hide` functions.  Create it as an `onClick` event rather than a `mouseenter` and/or `mouseOver` event.  Again, you won't get the greatest of feels for your menus using JS and it's recommended to use CSS but the `.toggle` would be a good alternative to the mouse events I think

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azPUC/) for you using easy and basic CSS to get the results you want.

Comment: If you had control over the HTML produced, you could put the `ul` inside another element, like a `div` or even a `span` _then_ you could easily use the mouse events to trigger the `.hide` and `.show` functions with the results you want but without control over the HTML you won't be able to produce the results you want with JS

Comment: Thanks,  I cannot seem to get the CSS only option working here: http://jzm.co.nz/clients/electro/trials

Comment: I inspected the elements on the page and I don't see where you added any of the CSS for the hiding/hovering of the element

Comment: That's strange... I went into web developer on firefox, went to Edit CSS and found your .current CSS... It had some wierd ASCII characters in a bad place.  When I deleted these characters, the CSS works properly on the page.  Go into firefox (assuming you have the web developer plugin) and Edit CSS.  You will see what I'm talking about.  I've seen this happen before from some editors inserting ascii characters in odd places.  You can't view it in your editor, but they become visible on the actual page viewed outside the editor

Comment: This is what the CSS looks like to me: `/*.current */
.currentânt > ul {
display: none;
}
.current:hover > ul {
display: block;
}â
/* Misc */` except after the a with the ^ over it, it has two boxes with unknown characters in it

Comment: here is a screenshot of what I see: http://f.imgtmp.com/ATXw4.png delete those characters and the CSS makes the menu work like you expect it too

Answer (score 2):

Hey This might not be the exactly what you are asking for, but this will solve your problem.

Add this to your CSS & remove that jQuery script

```
​.curre​nt > ul {
display: none;
}

​.current:hover > ul {
display: block;
}​
```

Because even if for some vague reason your jQuery is not working, let me tell you even if you get it running it will not produce desired result.

Comment: Very true tea. CSS seems like a better solution.

Comment: Thanks,  I cannot seem to get the CSS only option working here: http://jzm.co.nz/clients/electro/trials

Comment: Where it's not working ? You mean once you have clicked on Trials and you are redirected to other page ?